# Add / Remove attribute only working first time in loop

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to loop around some radio buttons checking them one at a time, but unfortunately the CSS `:checked` css selector only works the *first time* I do it?!

Easiest way to see what I'm talking about is the example below:

http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/2b490930b4a2b4e33d5c1e734f05302d

How do I make it loop, and make the CSS selector work the whole time? I'm looking at it in Chrome, so it might be a Chrome bug, or, more likely I'm doing something wrong somewhere..

**Some pictures:**

First time around (the black dots are a span selected using `:checked + span`, the number is the array index that should be checked):

[image: http://snag.gy/53qaL.jpg]

Second time around:

[image]

If you inspect element you'll see the boxes are checking correctly.

HTML:

```
<div id="notes">
  <input class="clap" type="radio" name="note" /><span></span>
  <input class="clap" type="radio" name="note" /><span></span>
  <input class="clap" type="radio" name="note" /><span></span>
  <input type="radio" name="note" /><span></span>
  <input class="clap" type="radio" name="note" /><span></span>
  <input class="clap" type="radio" name="note" /><span></span>
  <input type="radio" name="notes" /><span></span>
  <input class="clap" type="radio" name="notes" /><span></span>
  <input type="radio" name="note" /><span></span>
  <input class="clap" type="radio" name="note" /><span></span>
  <input class="clap" type="radio" name="note" /><span></span>
  <input type="radio" name="note" /><span></span>
</div>
<p>
  <span id="output"></span>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
$borderWidth: 2px;

body{
  text-align:center;
  font-family: 'Hammersmith One', sans-serif;
}

#notes{
  padding:2em 0;
}

p{
  margin:2em 0;
}

input{
  display:none;
}
input + span{
  border-radius:400px;
  border:$borderWidth solid black;
  background:white;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position:relative;
  &:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:-$borderWidth;
    border-radius:400px;
    border:2px solid black;
    background:white;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position:relative;
  }
}

input.clap + span{
  background:#16ab68;
  &:after{
    background:#16ab68;
  }
}

input:checked + span{
  background:#000;
  &:after{
    background:#000;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
var bpm = 130;
var intervalGap = 60000 / bpm;
var tick = true;

var phraseLength = 12;
var current = phraseLength - 1;

setInterval(function(){  
  current += 1;
  if(current >= phraseLength){
    current = 0;
  }

  $("#notes input").removeAttr("checked");

  var currentInput = $("#notes input")[current];

  $(currentInput).attr("checked","true");

  $("#output").html(current);

},intervalGap);
```

Comment: If you're using a newer version of jQuery you will want to use prop() instead of attr(): http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using prop fixes the problem, .prop() instead of .attr()

```
$(currentInput).prop("checked",true);
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KDqHw/)

Comment: or `currentInput.checked = true`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix - http://jsfiddle.net/Cg7z8/

Change -

```
  $(currentInput).attr("checked","true");
```

to

```
  $(currentInput).prop("checked","true");
```

Tested in FF with jQuery .1.10.0